# How to minimize n-polytope's bounding box with linear transformation?

Tags: matrices, convex-polytopes, linear-programming, integer-programming

I am working on an exact algorithm for integer linear programming for my master's thesis:
 
$Ax\leq b, x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$
$cx\rightarrow min$

For my idea to work out, I need a guarantee that n-polytope {$Ax\leq b$} has minimal bounding box - there is no unimodular matrix $M$ such that n-polytope {$AMx\leq b$} has smaller bounding box. Here "smaller" can mean anything reasonable - smaller by total volume, by smallest dimension, by largest dimension - I can make it work anyway.
What I need is an algorithm that for any $A$, $b$ produces matrix $M$ such that n-polytope {$AMx\leq b$} has minimal bounding box.
Initially, I thought that I can just check that all elementary column addition matrices do not give improvement for bounding box, because any unimodular matrix can be obtained as product of such elementary matrices, but I was wrong: 3-polytope $Conv(\{(a,0,0),(0,a,0),(0,0,a)\})$ has bounding box $a\times a\times a$, and it cannot be made smaller by any elementary transformation, yet this polytope is a flat triangle and as such can be made to have $0\times a\times a$ bounding box by an obvious unimodular linear transformation:
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 &  1 &  0 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
So, my algorithm can miss arbitrarily big opportunities to decrease bounding box of a polytope. This is unacceptable. This problem looks like something already solved, but I was not able to find anything in web (turns out, there is a famous problem of packing polytopes in rectangular boxes and it is not what I need at all).
There is an alternative way to state my problm: find vector $v$ such that function $f = vx$ has smallest difference between maximum and minimum across n-polytope {$Ax\leq b$}.
All the matrices and vectors are over integers here.
I will be grateful for any results relevant to my problem, even if they are partial, as I am quite stuck right now.